# Install SQL Server on Debian

Tags: sql-server, installation, debian

I want to install SQL Server on Linux. From MS site I read that Red Hat, SUSE, and Ubuntu are supported but I want to use it under Debian. Since Ubuntu is based on Debian, is there a chance to succeed with installation?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This worked for me on Debian 8 (Jessie) when I installed the pre-2017 vNext for [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk):

1. `apt-get install curl apt-transport-https sudo`
2. add `deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main` to `/etc/apt/sources.list`
3. `apt-get update && apt-get install -t jessie-backports openssl ca-certificates`
4. `curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -`
5. `curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server.list | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-server.list`
6. `apt-get update && apt-get install mssql-server`
7. `sudo /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf setup`

However I tried and failed to get the RTM Linux version of 2017 installed on Debian Stretch, ultimately using Ubuntu.

Comment: The server list name was changed. It is now https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server-2017.list

Comment: Another problem I came across was the missing libssl1.0.0 package in debian 9. This solved it: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/394456/how-to-convince-dpkg-that-libssl1-0-2-is-libssl1-0-0

Comment: Using this path, SQL Server was apparently installed but I couldn't connect to it no matter what. I got errors "Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : TCP Provider: Error code 0x2749." and "Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : TCP Provider: Error code 0x2749.Error code 0x102" and couldn't fix them (I've tried many things). I decided to use docker instead, and it worked (apparently). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @galmeida Debian 8 or 9?

Comment: It's Debian 9..

Comment: Stopped at this message: `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mssql-server : Depends: libssl1.0.0 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`. Solutions try to use a missing file: `http://ftp.se.debian.org/debian/pool/main/o/openssl/openssl_1.0.2l-1~bpo8+1_amd64.deb`

Comment: @i486 you probably aren't using Debian 8 (Jessie) then?

Comment: @JackDouglas Yes, it is Debian 9.7.

Comment: @i486 check the last line of my answer: "However I tried and failed to get the RTM Linux version of 2017 installed on Debian Stretch"

Comment: but let us know if you manage to get it to work!

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there is a chance the installation will succeed, or that you can work around any issues.  It wouldn't be a supported configuration, but it might work.

You also can try the [docker image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker).

Answer (score 4):

apt:

```
$ curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo apt-key add -
$ curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server.list | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-server.list
```

Update apt package database and install mssql-server package:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install mssql-server
```

After package installation, you need to run:

```
$ /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr-setup script:
$ sudo /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr-setup
```

[Microsoft(R) SQL Server(R) Setup](https://linux-tips.com/t/installing-microsoft-sql-server-on-debian-linux/476)